# Scroll down then scroll right then scroll down again

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, window, scrollbar

I have 3 separate divs.
First one 100vw and 100vh.
Second one has 100vw and 100vh and it has a div(".move") inside of 400vw and 100vh - which will be moving later on to the left and to the right.
Third one is 100vw and 100vh.

When I scroll down, I want the second div to get position fixed. (at this point div third jumps into div second position).
Then I want to scroll to the right of div ".move". 
At the end of scroll I want to add position absolute to div second and keep scrolling down through div third.

I dont know how much should I keep adding to scrollX (or translateX(-?px) or left = -?   , doesnt matter I guess)  so it is equal to normal scrollY at the end.

Also when I scroll quickly it jumps to div third and div ".move" barely get scrolled.

I would like to do it either useing scrollbar or mousewheel.

It should look like in this page:
bitsens.com/

And this is my current code:
codepen.io/Baromaro/pen/yLLMWMM

(the code is so sad..)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: please give me some example?